# how exactly does Messages work in play 2.0 framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Kindly correct and elaborate if my understanding is wrong.
Messages class is loaded at the startup of play application and Messages file ,as per default locale, is read and stored as key value pair which we can access using get() method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. The Java Messages API essentially just calls the Scala API. So Messages.get("key") in the Java API calls Messages.apply("key") in the Scala API.

The actual data does not live in Messages though, instead it is implemented as a play plugin play.api.MessagesPlugin which is initialized on app start. The plugin will load the message file of each language that you have specified with the configuration key application.langs in 'conf/application.conf'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please provide the link where i can check for source code of Messages and MessagesPlugin.

Comment: Here is the source code: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala

Comment: Note that the full sources also is included in the play distribution, so if you look in the unpacked play directory you have everything in framework/src/ and also note that Nicos link is to play master which may contain changes that arent in any released version of play yet.

Comment: @johanandren I checked in framework/src but i got only Messages.java file.I am unable to find play.api.MessagesPlugin file for play 2.0 anywhere.Please provide me any link

Comment: It's a Scala class and in Scala you can put more than one class in the same file and hence you might call the files something else than one of the classes inside of it. MessagesPlugin lives together with the Messages class in framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala

Comment: @johanandren Messages and MessagesPlugin classes are in Messages.scala. One Message class is in framework/src. I am getting confused as which Message class is called and when. How to undersatnd this messages implementation :( :(

Comment: @johanandren Messages files which are loaded on application startup and Messages.get(<key>) which fetch the value of corresponding key works on server side or client side.can you please confirm.

Comment: Play has got both a Java API and a Scala API, the Scala API is normally the actual implementation and the Java just calls it but provides the Java developers with an API that looks more like Java APIs normally do.